# Validate Md5PasswordEncoder hash without Java?

Tags: java, spring, hash, spring-security, md5

We're moving some of our backend API calls from Java to Node, but we have been using Md5PasswordEncoder to hash passwords with salts.

If I run the following:

```
Md5PasswordEncoder pe = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
pe.encodePassword("1", "1");
```

I get the result:

```
6a8a1f634e38d30e87b450899b31f810
```

However if I manually hash "11" I get:

```
6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca
```

I've tried other combinations of pass and salt, but I can't figure out how Md5PasswordEncoder is combining the salt with the password. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is how `salt` works. It should not just be appended to a given String, but modify the String on character / byte value level. My understanding of a good salt (which is not necessary the correct understanding) is, that you do some math with the byte values of characters, such as simple multiplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple when you [check the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java#BasePasswordEncoder.mergePasswordAndSalt%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29)

The salt is added as

```
String merged = password + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";
```

so get a MD5 of `1{1}` and voilà!

Note that as far as I know this is not a "standard" way to add salt. In literature it is often just said that "the salt is added to the password" without going into details on how it's added, prepended or appended, with some special markings like the `{}` in the above implementation or not. The important thing is to just make sure that all handlers of the hash know of the way the salt is added (otherwise you get into the situation of the question).